# Random patches on the screen after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, video, screen, 20.04

[image]

After upgrading my system from 19.04 to 20.04, some random patches started to appear. Those patterns appear only on the desktop, and not on other application windows nor terminal screens which can be accessed via CTRL+ALT+F. Also, interestingly, if I change a background image, they disappear for a while, then appear again.

I believe it's not an issue of physical devices. But I'm not sure if I'm just missing some crucial packages or some of the packages have bugs in it.

```
$ apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-intel
xserver-xorg-video-intel:
  Installed: 2:2.99.917+git20200226-1
  Candidate: 2:2.99.917+git20200226-1
  Version table:
  *** 2:2.99.917+git20200226-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

```
$ lspci -nnk
... omitted ...
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09)
        DeviceName: 32
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HD Graphics 5500 [103c:2248]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
... omitted ...
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux ProBook 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or have the same issue?

Comment: The same problem here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what works for me:

Create /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
  Driver      "intel"
  Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

Reboot

However, I found that the system is somewhat sluggish with above modification.

Much better results with:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
  Driver      "intel"
  Option      "DRI"  "3"
EndSection
```

One can experiment with values "FALSE", "1", "2", "3" for "DRI".
On my system, "2" gives the patches again, and glxgears won't run.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The latter solution works perfectly!!

Comment: Just to add some related info. I found the intel man page (https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/intel.4) quite helpful. It's very interesting that setting DRI level to 3, which is the maximum value, solved this issue because the documentation says, by default, it'll set the maximum supported value.
I guess somehow the supported DRI level was guessed wrong, and it automatically either disabled or set to the lower level (e.g. 2). I think this solution will force maximum DRI level to be 3, and solves the issue.